# equating addresses of a 2d array and a 1d array in c

Tags: c, arrays

This prog is to accept an array of chars n compress them....(aaaabbbcc-->a4b3c2)....my prog is showing error at the point where im equating the addr of the 2d array to 1d array. This is my code:

```
/* size1 defined as 5 and size2 as 10.... (consts)*/

void compress(char data[SIZE1][SIZE2]);

int main()
{
    char data[SIZE1][SIZE2];

    printf("Enter a 5x10 matrix of characters:\n");
    scanf("%c", &data);
    compress(data[SIZE1][SIZE2]);
    _getch();
    return 0;
}



void compress(char data[SIZE1][SIZE2])
{
    int hold[SIZE1*SIZE2];
    int cnt = 0;
    hold[SIZE1*SIZE2] = data[SIZE1][SIZE2];
    for (int i = 0; i < (SIZE1*SIZE2); i++)
    {
        if (hold[i] == hold[i + 1])
        {
            cnt++;
            continue;
        }
        else
        {
            printf("%c%d", hold[i], cnt);
        }
    }
}
```

This didn't work so I tried to use pointers:

```
void compress(char data[SIZE1][SIZE2])
{
    int *hold[SIZE1*SIZE2];
    int cnt = 0;
    hold = data[SIZE1][SIZE2];
    for (int i = 0; i < (SIZE1*SIZE2); i++)
    {
        if (*(hold+i) == *(hold+i+1))
        {
            cnt++;
        }
        else
        {
            printf("%c%d", *(hold+i), cnt);
        }
    }
}
```

I thought that the addrs of 2d arrays are stored linearly, hence they can be directly =to that of 1d.But the error says "'=':left operand must be an l-value".Im very new to pointers.Any help or corrections ....pls?

Comment: Please never ever use tabs in your posts!!! They will (did) make it nearly illegible and therefore less likely to get an answer. Nearly every editor has a function to replace tabs with spaces. It is a good idea no use tabs in your code in general since everyone has tabs configured differently.

Comment: A couple of issues. If `compress` has a variable `char data[SIZE1][SIZE2]` then you call it by `compress(data)` not `compress(data[SIZE1][SIZE2])`. The latter call only passes a single `char` instead of the variable representing the entire array. That character is undefined since the range of valid indices into `data` are `0` to `SIZE1-1` for the first, and `0` to `SIZE2-1` for the second. Also, `hold = data[SIZE1][SIZE2];` sets `hold` to character at `data[SIZE1][SIZE2]` (invalid, as noted) but `hold` is defined as an array of integer pointers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define SIZE1 3
#define SIZE2 3

void compress(char data[SIZE1][SIZE2]);

int main(){
    char data[SIZE1][SIZE2];

    printf("Enter a %dx%d matrix of characters:\n", SIZE1, SIZE2);
    for(int i=0;i<SIZE1;++i)
        for(int j=0;j<SIZE2;++j)
            scanf("%c", &data[i][j]);//aaaabbbcc
    compress(data);
    (void)getchar();
    return 0;
}

void compress(char data[SIZE1][SIZE2]){
    char *hold = &data[0][0];
    int cnt = 1, size = SIZE1*SIZE2;

    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++){
        if (i < size -1 && hold[i] == hold[i + 1]){
            cnt++;
            //continue;
        } else {
            printf("%c%d", hold[i], cnt);//a4b3c2
            cnt = 1;
        }
    }
}
```